# Why is there no 'ECDSA' version of 'DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305'?

Tags: elliptic-curves, dsa, chacha

So I was just checking my TLS cipherlist and noticed that there was a 'DSS' / `DSA` / `ECDSA` version of every `RSA` cipher available, except for `DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305`.

Why is that?

Comment: There [ought to be](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-tls-chacha20-poly1305-00#section-4.1), but the whole get of ChaCha20 + Poly1305 ciphers is still just a draft, so maybe not everyone's implemented them all.

Comment: The ChaCha suites are fairly new and I guess the authors of the RFC / tool decided that a) ECDSA is too rare for its own ciper suite or (more likely) b) that everybody using this fairly modern ChaCha wouldn't use "classic" + EC but rather use the superior ECDHE + ECDSA (after the EC code would already be there whereas when you don't use ECDHE it's assumed no ECC code's there).

Comment: @otus, I *think* the OP is asking why there's no `TLS_DHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305`

Comment: @SEJPM There is no DHE_ECDSA keyexchange in 5246 or 4492, so defining and requiring a new keyexchange for -chacha would greatly decrease its prospects. Ben: if you look carefully, there are MANY ciphersuites using plain RSA keyexchange with implicit auth and neither DSA/DSS or ECDSA,
although if you're looking at OpenSSL in particular these are slightly harder to recognize because the OpenSSL names omit the string RSA.
Ignoring anonymous and non-publickey, 5246 et pred and 4492 define only keyexchanges for DHE_{RSA,DSS} DH_{RSA,DSS} and ECDHE_{RSA,ECDSA} ECDH_{RSA,ECDSA} respectively, ...

Comment: ... So the only DHE other than DHE_RSA that -chacha could practically use is DHE_DSS, and it doesn't; is that your question?
(DSS in SSL/TLS *is* DSA, it's just that the names were chosen back in the 1990s before FIPS 186 contained algorithms other than DSA.)

Comment: @SEJPM, there's no DHE_ECDSA suite period, AFAICT, while he says there's a "... version of every RSA cipher" whatever that means.

Comment: You need ECDSA certificates for that. I think the industry is, by and large, going to eschew ECDSA certificates in favor of EDDSA certificates.

Comment: Some years later: my OpenSSL-1.1.1b does list `0xCCAA=DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305` and `0xCCA9=ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305`

Answer (score 1):

The original cipher suites involving ECDH and ECDSA were all introduced together in [RFC 4492](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4492).  They corresponded to existing cipher suites:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rcl} 
  \text{DH_DSS} &\longmapsto& \text{ECDH_ECDSA} \\
  \text{DHE_DSS} &\longmapsto& \text{ECDHE_ECDSA} \\
  \text{DH_RSA} &\longmapsto& \text{ECDH_RSA} \\
  \text{DHE_RSA} &\longmapsto& \text{ECDHE_RSA} \\
  \text{DH_anon} &\longmapsto& \text{ECDH_anon}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

One might infer that the thinking was if you were going to take the plunge into the world of elliptic curves—recall in 2006 elliptic curve cryptography had (and to some extent still has) an undeserved reputation for being new and poorly understood in contrast to modular exponentiation systems in finite (quasi-)fields—then you might as well use ECDH key agreement, while you might keep your long-term RSA certificate because it was costly to buy a new one.  Doing it the other way around—buying an ECDSA certificate but using finite-field DH key agreement—would just be silly.

(Recall that this was also perhaps the heyday of the HTTPS certificate authority protection racket, before the browsers collectively imposed any semblance of regulation on it by the CAB Forum and long before Let's Encrypt rendered it obsolete.)

One might further infer that nobody bothered to break this pattern, because why would you want to do any more finite-field DH key agreement in this day and age anyway?